# Is it possible to execute a Multi-Attack with two or more different weapons?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, attack

For example: if you are using a Maul, can you make an attack with it, sheath it, and then make an attack with a Greatsword, potentially doing this with four different weapons when unlocking the fighter's Extra Attack (4) feature?

Comment: Yes, my apologies.

Comment: Note that Extra Attack and Multiattack are two different abilities. Multiattack is what a monster might get, and it specifies exactly what attacks it must use (for example, bite, claw, claw). With Multiattack, you cannot uee different attacks or weapons, nor can you replace one of the attacks with a push or a grapple.